# How to seperate google signed-in user and native mail user in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application where I am implementing both Google Sign-In as well as Native mail. Firstly I implemented google sign-in to my application and it works properly.Then I created a Firebase Firestore to store data for registration. The registration also works properly but when I try to sign-in, I cannot seem to find the conditional logic to seperate which one is from Firestore/Native Mail and which one is from Google Sign-In.I am new to flutter so I might have some problem in my regular code too.

I also found similar questions here asked but when I implemented those, it still didn't work for me. This is why I have put this question again to solve for this particular situation.

Here's my initial code for the page that must be shown when a user logs in.

```
class LoggedInWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  const LoggedInWidget({super.key});

  @override
    LoggedInWidgetState createState() => LoggedInWidgetState();
}
class LoggedInWidgetState extends State<LoggedInWidget> {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users'); // Firestore Database
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;  // FirebaseAuth to get the current user.

  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();  //  Created a model in another page called UserModel 
  var name; 
  var email;
  var photo;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance     // Gets data from the current logged in user data and 
        .collection("users")       // saves it in a model called loggedInUser.
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value){
      loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      // setState(() {});
    });
    
    // This is the logic I implemented for seperating native mail and google sign-in as 
    // the loggedInUser will have no name there and will be directly associated to the User variable

    if(loggedInUser.name == null){  /
      name = user?.displayName;
      email = user?.email;
      photo = user?.photoURL;
    }
    else{
      name = loggedInUser.name!;
      email = loggedInUser.email;
    }
```

When running this code, I am able to get my google sign-in data successfully whereas when using Native mail to sign-in. I get the email (probably due to it being saved on the FirebaseAuth), but not the name and other details that is saved in the Firestore.

Comment: You say you stored data in **Firestore**, yet your code uses the API that accesses the Firebase Realtime Database (e.g. `final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users'); // Firestore Database`. Cloud Firestore and Firebase Realtime Databases are two separate databases, and the API for one doesn't access data in the other. To access data in Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Initially, I was using realtime database, then I shifted to Firestore. It was just leftover code when I used Realtime Database. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please update your question (there's an `edit` link right under it) to only include the code that is relevant to the current problem in that case. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as starting from scratch is the best way to avoid such leftover code that is distracting to us and thus decreases the chances that we'll spot the actual problem you're *now* dealing with.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the reply. This is the relevant code except the 'userref' line. But I found the solution to the problem. If I add the google account signed-in to Firestore then it can be easily used to retrieve values. without the need to seperate.